# Javascript variable function adding extra parameter

Tags: javascript

So I have a call back function as such

```
var subscription_callback0 = function(payload) {
                // do something
            };
```

and another function that will pass an object into the callback function

```
client.subscribe(dest1, subscription_callback);
```

The subscribe function above is called from a javascript library which will pass in the payload object when invoked and so the callback function definition is not under my control. But is there anyway that I can pass in an extra argument into the callback function ?

Comment: What extra argument? From where to where do you want to pass what? And which part of the code exactly is not under your control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Callback function that accepts another argument:

```
var subscription_callback = function (arg1, payload) {
    // do something
};
```

Bind the first argument:

```
client.subscribe(dest1, subscription_callback.bind(null, 'foo'));
```

Or pass it dynamically:

```
client.subscribe(dest1, function (payload) {
    subscription_callback('foo', payload);
});
```

Or closure it when you define the callback in the first place:

```
var foo = 'bar';

var subscription_callback = function (payload) {
    alert(foo);
    // do something
};
```

Comment: Thanks I think I like the dynamic solutions you gave me

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.bind()` to pass parameter to a function while assigning.

**Note:** *This is just a basic implementation of how to pass parameter to function.*

You can replace your code to

```
client.subscribe(dest1, subscription_callback.bind(variableName));
```

#### Sample

```js
function notify(str){
  console.log(str);
}

document.getElementById("btn").onclick = notify.bind(null, "clicked button");
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click Me!</button>
```